# Unclear on Nagle's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, networking, tcp

I've been doing some research on Nagle's algorithm out of idle curiousity. I understand the basic concept behind it (TCP packets contain a significant amount of overhead especially when dealing with small payloads), but I'm not sure I grok the implementation.

I was reading [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) on Wikipedia, but I'm still unclear on how it works. Let's take the example of a Telnet connection. The connection is established and I begin typing. Let's say I type three characters (`cat`, for example) and hit return. Now we're talking `cat\r\n` which is still only 5 bytes. I'd think this would not get sent until we queue up enough bytes to send - and yet, it **does** get sent immediately (from a user perspective), since `cat` is immediately executed upon hitting return.

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding here on how the algorithm works, specifically regarding the bit where "if there is unconfirmed data still in the pipe, enqueue, else send immediately."

Comment: The article talks about telnet sessions being a problem though, so it would send it immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data gets sent immediately only if the server has already responded to any previous messages from you (or this is your first contact with it in this session). So, as the server gets busier and slower to respond, in order to avoid swamping it with too many packets, the data gets queued up to a maximum packet size before getting sent.

So whether data gets sent immediately or not only can be determined in the context of previous messages, if any.

Comment: So I'm guessing Nagle's algorithm won't apply to SYN/ACK packets, then - i.e. it sends those without delay?

Comment: You can disable the nagle algorithm with the TCP_NODELAY option in the call to setsockopt.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this post](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml), it is quite in-depth and clarified a lot of the things for me.